# How to add an ellipsis after a sentence?

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

Suppose I have this sentence:

*Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release.*

I want just three lines. After the first 3 lines nothing will be shown except       **...** (ellipsis). 
Like:

*Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has surv...*

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-webkit-line-clamp` property to achieve what you want. If you want to clamp it to 3 lines, then `-webkit-line-clamp: 3` should be used. Despite it having a `-webkit` vendor prefix, it is [surprisingly quite widely support among modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp).

A caveat is that `-webkit-line-clamp` has to be used with two additional CSS properties: `display: -webkit-box` and `-webkit-box-orient: vertical`.

```css
.box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
  overflow: hidden;

  /** Presentation purposes only **/
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release.
</div>
```

Hopefully when CSS Overflow Module Level 3 becomes finalized and widely supported, we can start using the [non-prefixed `line-clamp` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#line-clamp) in the near future, with the ability to add custom overflowing text indicator. Right now, `-webkit-line-clamp` uses the horizontal ellipsis glyph to indicate cutoff text, but with no possibility to customize it.